# Both the first name and the last name last name in single text box

Tags: regex

I have a text box where i get the last name of user. How do I allow only one hyphen (-),only one space( ),only one apostrophe (') in a regular expression and at least 2 character in first name and one space then last name.Both the first name and the last name last name in single text box.
I am using now this regular expression. 
    ^(?!.*-.*-.*)(?!.*'.*'.*)(?!.*\s.*\s.*)[a-z A-Z]{1,24}[a-z A-Z- ']+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hyphen: `(?![^-]*-[^-]*-)`
One space: `(?![^ ]* [^ ]* )`
One apostrophe: `(?![^']*'[^']*')`
At least 2 characters: `[\w-' ]{2,} [\w-' ]{2,}`

So, to summarize:

```
/(?![^-]*-[^-]*-)(?![^ ]* [^ ]* )(?![^']*'[^']*')([\w-']{2,}) ([\w-']{2,})/
```

This would also catch the first name and last name in the 1st and 2nd capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this website to build all your regexp

visit http://gskinner.com/RegExr/